# My friend (32 male) and his wife is having a baby girl, can I gift the baby gold earrings?

Tags: halal-haram, gold

I'm a Christian man, and I have a male Muslim best friend who is having a baby girl next week and I wanted to gift the baby a pair of gold earrings. I wanted to know from an Islamic point of view if that would be OK to do so?

We're both very close friends and share a lot with each other, and I also know his wife very well as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! you can gift the infant *girl*, any gold ornament because in the Quran:

> Do they assign to Allah one who grows up amidst ornaments and is not well-versed in the art of disputation? (43:18)

Here Allah mentions that wearing adornments is an attribute of women; this includes gold and other things.

And Ahmad, Abu Dawood and al-Nasaa’i narrated with a jayyid isnaad from Ameer al-Mu’mineen ‘Ali ibn Abi Taalib that

> “These two [gold and silk] are forbidden for the males of my ummah.”

Ibn Maajah added in one narration

> “and permitted for the females.”

Also It was narrated by Ahmad from Abu Moosa al-Ash’ari, that the Prophet (saw) said:

> “Gold and silk have been permitted for the females of my ummah, and forbidden for the males.”

So it permitted for females to wear gold ornaments and is not permitted for males As the Prophet (saw) concerning gold and silk said :

> **"These two things are forbidden to the males of my ummah.”** Narrated by Abu Dawood (3535) and an-Nasaa’i (5054); classed as saheeh by Shaykh al-Albaani.

Also for the ruling of the four madhab of males wearing gold is that:
**The Hanafis and Hanbalis, and some of the Shaafa‘is, are of the view that it is haraam for males to wear gold, whether they are young or old, except in cases of necessity. The Maalikis are of the view that it is permissible for a boy to wear gold, although it is makrooh (disliked). Another Shaafa‘is view is that it is permissible in general. According to another view, it is permissible before the age of two years and it is prohibited after that.**

---

Comment: Great answer, but can you describe how the first verse you have linked has much to do with the permissibility of gold for women?

Comment: @LILLOFIE Thanks, and the origin of [43:18] is that some idolaters/polytheist associated daughters (maybe it's lat, mannat and uzza or the Angels) to Allah, while they wished for sons. So Allah exposed their hypocrisy as they are associating something to Allah that they themselves do no wish/hope for. Allah then says why do they associate something to Allah that is fragile and *covered in ornament*, **this means that ornaments are natural and attributed for women by/in the sight_of Allah**. This is a additional Quranic reference and all later confusions/queries are cleared/explained in Hadith.

Comment: For more about 43:18, see the tafseer given [here](https://myislam.org/surah-zukhruf/ayat-18/#:~:text=(43%3A18)%20Do%20they,is%20bold%2C%20courageous%20and%20fearless.).

Comment: @AbdulRahman Alright, got it, thanks!